# SpringBootTest - how to replace one bean in runtime configuration?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test for Spring Boot application. All goes well as long as I'm using 100% runtime configuration for the test. But when I'm trying to provide just one custom bean for the bean, everything breaks.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CombinedControllerIntegrationTest2 {

@TestConfiguration
static class ContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository solrDocumentTypeMapRepository() {
        LOG.debug("SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository is being initialized.");

// etc.
```

code variant above is causing the real runtime `SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository` to load. Therefore the `ContextConfiguration` in my test class is ignored.

If I try to use `@Configuration` instead of `@TestConfiguration` on my inner `ContextConfiguration`, execution falls to another extreme - it ends with:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing
EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Because, apparently, the rest of configuration is not loaded.

If I try to put

```
@ContextConfiguration(
 classes = { CombinedControllerIntegrationTest2.ContextConfiguration.class,
             GatewayApplication.class})
```

on my main testing class, it fails the same way as in #1 - i.e. my `ContextConfiguration` is ignored.

Any ideas?

P.S. I know I can use `@MockBean` (and this even works in other cases), but here, because at some point I have dependency on `@PostConsruct` methods in the main code, `@MockBeans` are useless.

Comment: I faced similar issue as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45522778/springboottest-not-creating-inner-beans-while-loading-the-context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Unit Test with One Bean

Just use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation, it should work. You can also use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. Both should work.

**Please don't use** `@SpringBootTest` annotation. It will wire up the whole application.

Here is your updated example,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CombinedControllerIntegrationTest2 {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository solrDocumentTypeMapRepository() {
            LOG.debug("SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository is being initialized.");
            return new SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository(...);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(repository);
    }
}
```

#### Integration Test with a Replaced Bean

- Create a new test Spring Boot application. It should exclude the configuration class (for e.g., `SolrConfiguration`)  which is responsible for creating `SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository` bean.

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
          "com.abc.pkg1",
          "com.abc.pk2"},
          excludeFilters = {
                  @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, 
                  value = SolrConfiguration.class)})
  public class TestApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```
- Now, use the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation in your test class to add the `TestApplication.class` and the `ContextConfiguration.class`. This will wire up your application with the all the required beans including the replaced bean. Shown below is the updated test class,

  ```
  @ActiveProfiles("test")
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = 
      SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApplication.class, 
      CombinedControllerIntegrationTest2.ContextConfiguration.class})
  public class CombinedControllerIntegrationTest2 {

      @TestConfiguration
      static class ContextConfiguration {

          @Bean
          public SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository solrDocumentTypeMapRepository() {
              LOG.debug("SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository is being initialized.");
              return new SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository(...);
          }
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I'm doing for _unit_ tests. Not using @SpringBootTest annotation here would mean that I'm not doing integration test. My application has dozens of other beans that I do want to use.

Comment: @Alexander Updated my posting to show you can use the replaced bean along with rest of your application beans in your integration test.

Comment: Thank you! "TestApplication" approach worked. I still kind of disappointed in "@TestConfiguration" annotation. Spring documentation leads to believe that it enables partial configuration overriding, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, Spring document doesn't cover or clear about corner use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@MockBean` to mock your repository. And add behavior in the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)      
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
     
  @MockBean
  SolrDocumentTypeMapRepository solrDocumentTypeMapRepository;
 
  @Test
  public void mySuperTest(){ 
Mockito.when(solrDocumentTypeMapRepository.getById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(someInstance);
Assert.assertEquals(solrDocumentTypeMapRepository.getById("someId"), someInstance);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using @Runwith(SpringJunit4Classrunner.class) use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class). That should help you with the error.

Comment: Nope, this does not change anything.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html), there is no difference: _Simply annotate a JUnit 4 based test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`_