# Spring boot test - No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.MyService' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

There are a number of similar questions on stackoverflow, but I found none to be my case.

In my integration test with Spring boot **2.0.2.RELEASE**, I created a separate @Configuration class for the test where I did define the bean `com.example.MyService`. This bean happens to be used by some other bean in `com.example.OtherBean`.

Here is the code:

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyIntegrationTestConfig.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class MyService1Test extends MyAbstractServiceIntegrationTest {
@Test
    public void someTest() {}
}
```

A common abstract for setup and teardown:

```
public class MyAbstractServiceIntegrationTest{
    @Before
    public void setUp(){}

    @After
    public void tearDown()
}
```

MyIntegrationTestConfig in src/test, to be used instead of the configs in the src/main:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
public class MyIntegrationTestConfig {
   @Bean
   public MyService myService() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

`MyService` bean can be null for testing purposes.

When I run the test, I keep getting the following error:

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I even tried adding this inner class to MyServic1Test. Still didn't help:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class MyServic1TestContextConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "MyService")
    public MyService myService() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Or did I miss something?

My suspicion is that Spring tries to create/autowire beans in the src/main folder first before it even creates the MyService bean defined in src/test folder. Could that be the case? Or is there a different context (like test context) where bean MyService lives in, while the other beans live in an other context and could not locate MyService.

A side question: for integration test, it is OK to use webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, correct?

Comment: Try to return `new MyService()` instead of `null` just to check if the error persists.

Comment: Hah, @NiVeR. the error seems to go away. Now I face a bunch of beans to do like that. Question: Can I use @ MockBean inside the @ Configuration MyIntegrationTestConfig class? I tried, it seems OK, but not sure if that is the right thing to do inside a Configuration class.

Comment: So maybe the final question is, why Spring boot treats null as no bean? Just searched, didn't find any relevant docs for that.

Comment: For the last question there is this good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java.

Comment: @Simo your question includes some nice code! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are initializing the bean. The value `null` is the one that causes the issue. It is as if you weren't infact declaring any instance of that object. To make it work declare a valid instance of the service `new MyService()`.